# SwiftUI - Is it possible to update initialized parameters?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swiftui

In my code, I am passing `post.id` from a view to my view model. In order for my comments to show up, I need to init getComments. Previously, before I was passing `post.id`, I simply had the line `init(){getComments(id: "E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S")}`. `E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S` is a document that already had comments on it, so I could test to make sure comments actually loaded.

Now, since every post is to have a different set of comments, I need to change the id based on what what post the user is requesting comments on. To do this, like I said I am passing post.id and printing it (to make sure that it's actually passed).

In my code, the init() is required to show comments. Because of the way that my comments are shown, initializing getComments is a requirement. Without the init, comments shows up with a ProgressView and goes nowhere else.

My question is, can I update initialized parameters? If I'm initializing `getComments(id: "E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S")`, is there anyway that I can update `E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S` to the passed post.id?

I can't just set it to `getComments(id: post.id)` because by default, no ID is passed, so I get the Thread 1: Nil error. I'm thinking I need a default value that updates when a user clicks the comments button.

*CommentsViewModel.swift*

```
class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var comments: [CommentsModel] = []
    @Published var noComments = false
    @Published var newComment = false
    @Published var commentTxt = ""

    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    var post: PostModel? {
        didSet{
            if let post = self.post {
                getComments(id: post.id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(){getComments(id: "E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S")}

    func getComments(id: String) {
        print("ID from getComments is: \(id)")
    }
```

*CommentsView.swift - showing the ProgressView and showing comments*

```
@StateObject var commentsData = CommentsViewModel()
```

```
if commentsData.comments.isEmpty{
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                if commentsData.noComments{
                    Text("No Comments")
                }
                else{
                    Text("Test")
                }
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            else{
ScrollView{
                    VStack(spacing: 15){
                        
                        ForEach(commentsData.comments){comment in
                            
                            CommentsRow(post: post, comment: comment, commentData: commentsData)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.bottom,55)
                }
                .onAppear {
                  commentsData.post = post
                }
```

*PostRow.swift - the button that actually displays comments*

```
    var CommentsData: CommentsViewModel
    @State private var showingComments = false
```

```
 Button(action: {
                    showingComments = true
                    commentsData.getComments(id: post.id)
                }){
                    Text("Comments")
                }
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingComments)
                {
                    CommentsView(post: post)
                }
```

**Edit:** with both `init(){getComments(id: "E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S")}` and `if let post = self.post {getComments(id: post.id)}`, both ID's print in console, but then `E1m3U1FoeCbOwBGPPq4S` is the ID that is actually used to show the comments.

Comment: You call `getComments` on `commentsData` in PostRow.swift, but that is a different instance of `commentsData` than the one in `CommentsView`, right? I'm pretty sure that explains the issues you've had from the beginning. You need to call `getComments` on the instance of `CommentsViewModel` that is inside `CommentsView.swift` -- right now, you're calling it on the one owned by `PostRow`, which is *not the same*.

Comment: That would explain the misunderstanding of why `init` was required, because `init` is the *only* thing getting called on the version in `CommentsView`. There is no such thing as initializing a function in Swift, so doing something in `init` doesn't endow it with special properties. But, in this case, it was probably the only one actually taking place. If `comments.isEmpty` is `true`, then the `onAppear` never gets called.

Comment: Oh, this makes a lot of sense. How would I call getComments from the instance of CommentsViewModel? Your answer makes total sense to me. Although, I think the onAppear gets called? Not entirely sure.

Comment: Call it in `onAppear`, but make sure it will happen some place that will actually get called. Right now, if `comments.isEmpty`, it will never get called. You should be able to use the debugger to see if the the current one gets called, but I don't see how it could -- it looks like it's inside the `else` block. Or, other simple debugging: use a `print` statement to see.

Comment: Alright so, I added print to my .onAppear of the ScrollView - and nothing printed. So you're right, its not getting called.

Comment: The onAppear should be somewhere where it gets called each time. For example, a Group or VStack surrounding all of the body code

Comment: This actually seemed to fix the problem. Moving the .onAppear made it work. Would you mind making this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current setup, you have different instances of `CommentsViewModel`. When the `Button` gets pressed, `getComments` is called, but it is called on a different instance than is used in `CommentsView`.

Inside `CommentsView`, your current code only calls `getComments` when comments already exist. If you move `getComments` and the surrounding `onAppear` somewhere that it will reliably get called, your code should start to work.

Comment: Alright well now that this actually works, I'm facing another error. When I open a post with comments, and then close the CommentsView, then reopen it, the comments reload so theres two of each comment. If you do it again, you'll have three of each comment, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to use the debugger again to see when the view model is being created, when the comments are being set, etc. But, I believe this is a separate question.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out now. If I can't figure it out, I'll make a new question. I just don't want to post a ton of questions and annoy people

Comment: Posting multiple questions isn't a bad thing, as long as they're unique. It's also helpful to create as much of a [mre] as possible. In this case, this question had multiple iterations over time and it is frustrating when they get deleted, removing context and conversation in future versions. I think I probably would've caught the issue with the different instances of `CommentsViewModel` early on if it had been clear in the included code.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the information - I'll try to post more code with my questions in the future so they they're understandable.